# How to implement request number increase during load test using Node.js loadtest?

Tags: node.js, load-testing

I would like to implement some kind of request number increase during the load test.
For example, start with 10 req/s and for every 100 requests, increase by another 10 req/s, until there are 200 req/s.

I'm using Node.js [loadtest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loadtest) library